# Azure event hub lower throughput in egress from all partitions

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-eventhub

I'm building an application that consumes events from all partitions of the Azure event hub. I'm facing the issue of lower ingest rate. In starting application getting high ingest rate and getting lower by time.

code is as shown in spring-boot snippets

```
private Disposable subscription;
private EventHubConsumerAsyncClient client;

client = new EventHubClientBuilder()
                    .connectionString(ehProps.getConnectionString(), ehProps.getEventHubName())
                    .consumerGroup(ehProps.getStorage().getConsumerGroupName()).buildAsyncConsumerClient();
            subscription = client.receive(true).subscribe(new EventProcessor());
```

EventProcessor service

```
@Service
public class EventProcessor implements Consumer<PartitionEvent> {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;

    @Override
    public void accept(PartitionEvent event) {

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 1000) {
            count++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Events per second ::" + count);
            count = 0;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

    }

}
```

Colsole o/p

```
2020-04-30 19:50:11.024  INFO 6906 --- [       single-1] c.a.m.e.EventHubConsumerAsyncClient      : connectionId[MF_dcd848_1588256404924] linkName[all_fd160b_1588256404998-2]: Creating receive consumer for partition '2'
2020-04-30 19:50:11.024  INFO 6906 --- [       single-1] c.a.c.a.implementation.ReactorSession    : linkName[all_fd160b_1588256404998-2] entityPath[spring-event-hub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/2]: Returning existing receive link.
2020-04-30 19:50:11.024  INFO 6906 --- [       single-1] c.a.c.a.i.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler     : onLinkLocalOpen connectionId[MF_dcd848_1588256404924], linkName[all_fd160b_1588256404998-0], localSource[Source{address='spring-event-hub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/0', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter={apache.org:selector-filter:string=UnknownDescribedType{descriptor=apache.org:selector-filter:string, described=amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset > '-1'}}, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}]
2020-04-30 19:50:11.026  INFO 6906 --- [       single-1] c.a.c.a.i.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler     : onLinkLocalOpen connectionId[MF_dcd848_1588256404924], linkName[all_fd160b_1588256404998-1], localSource[Source{address='spring-event-hub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/1', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter={apache.org:selector-filter:string=UnknownDescribedType{descriptor=apache.org:selector-filter:string, described=amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset > '-1'}}, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}]
2020-04-30 19:50:11.026  INFO 6906 --- [       single-1] c.a.c.a.i.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler     : onLinkLocalOpen connectionId[MF_dcd848_1588256404924], linkName[all_fd160b_1588256404998-2], localSource[Source{address='spring-event-hub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/2', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter={apache.org:selector-filter:string=UnknownDescribedType{descriptor=apache.org:selector-filter:string, described=amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset > '-1'}}, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}]
2020-04-30 19:50:11.466  INFO 6906 --- [       single-1] c.a.c.a.i.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler     : onLinkRemoteOpen connectionId[MF_dcd848_1588256404924], linkName[all_fd160b_1588256404998-1], remoteSource[Source{address='spring-event-hub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/1', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter={apache.org:selector-filter:string=org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.DecoderImpl$UnknownDescribedType@2615c490}, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}]
2020-04-30 19:50:11.467  INFO 6906 --- [       single-1] c.a.c.a.i.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler     : onLinkRemoteOpen connectionId[MF_dcd848_1588256404924], linkName[all_fd160b_1588256404998-0], remoteSource[Source{address='spring-event-hub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/0', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter={apache.org:selector-filter:string=org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.DecoderImpl$UnknownDescribedType@76700147}, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}]
2020-04-30 19:50:11.470  INFO 6906 --- [       single-1] c.a.c.a.i.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler     : onLinkRemoteOpen connectionId[MF_dcd848_1588256404924], linkName[all_fd160b_1588256404998-2], remoteSource[Source{address='spring-event-hub/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/2', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter={apache.org:selector-filter:string=org.apache.qpid.proton.codec.DecoderImpl$UnknownDescribedType@52d562e3}, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}]
Events per second ::0
Events per second ::316
Events per second ::818
Events per second ::409
Events per second ::87
Events per second ::21
Events per second ::12
Events per second ::5
Events per second ::3
Events per second ::4
Events per second ::3
Events per second ::4
Events per second ::4
Events per second ::5
Events per second ::5
```

Side note: I have tested by increasing TU, but no luck

Comment: How many events do you have on each partition? Are you also running senders during the your tests?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca there is 34.5K events on each partition and there were no senders during the test.

Comment: @Nikhil Can you try receiving from a single partition and see what throughput you get? 

client.receiveFromPartition("0", EventPosition.earliest()).subscribe(new EventProcessor());

I tested your sample and was able to consistently receive ~6000 events per second.

Comment: @srikanta Thank you for your suggestion, I have tested with a single partition but same issue. Console OP https://github.com/nikhilmalavia/AzureConsumer/blob/master/Console

Comment: @Nikhil your network or proxy might be limiting the throughput. It might also be because of the Azure location your Event Hubs namespace is in. Try picking a location that is geographically closer to your application.